# Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, downcast

I am saving a parse query to a array but i ket the following error on if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]

And the following error happens Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals.

any one know how to solve this?

```html
func getArray(funcstring: String){
        
        var userGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint
        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
        
            userGeoPoint = geoPoint!
            }
        }
        
        
        var searchQuery: [String] = [String]()
        
        var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
        query.whereKey("geoLocation", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint)
        query.limit = 100
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.searchQuery.append(object.objectForKey("objectId") as! String)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            } else {
                print("\(error?.userInfo)")
            }
        }

        
        
        
        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`objects` is declared as `[PFObject]?`.

You're going to downcast the object to something the compiler already knows.

Just check for `nil`

```
if let unwrappedObjects = objects {
  for object in unwrappedObjects {
     self.searchQuery.append(object.objectForKey("objectId") as! String)    
  }
}
```

or still "swiftier"

```
if let unwrappedObjects = objects {
   self.searchQuery = unwrappedObjects.map{ $0["objectId"] as! String }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response it worked but now i get the following error as self.searchQuery.append.... , Value of type "viewcontroller " has no member 'searchQuery'

Comment: `searchQuery ` is supposed to be declared on class scope (as instance variable) rather than in the `getArray()` method or if it's really meant as a local variable omit `self`

Comment: Sorry im new to coding where abouts should i declare it

Comment: Class scope means within the top braces `class viewController : UIViewController { var  ...   }`